# How to render differently a django model object field on a html page?

Tags: python, django

My model object have a IntegerField but I want to be able to render it differently on my html page, like lets say the object IntegerField is `500000` I want to render it as `500 000$` on my html page. So Add a space before the `last 3 number` and add a `$` at the end.

I have a models with a IntegerField that look like this

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=100)
```

In my view I extract the models like this

```
def home(request):
    listing_object = Listing.objects.all()
    context = {
        "listing_object": listing_object,
    }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

I render the data like this

```
{% for listing in listing_new_object %}
{{listing.listing_price}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Manipulate the context to make a list of tuples:

```py
context = {
    "listing_object": [(listing, f'{listing.listing_price:,}'.replace(",", " ")) for listing in listing_object]
}
```

then in your template:

```html
{% for _, price in listing_new_object %}
{{price}}
{% endfor %}
```

- The other option is to make a Django template filter

```html
{{ listing.listing_price|price_format }}
```

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


def price_format(value):
    return f'{value:,}'.replace(",", " ")

register.filter(price_format)
```